# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, primary-key, sqlbulkcopy

I am dumping millions of records in my table using sql bulk copy.I process my data and prepare datatable and once size reach to 1000 records i use [Sql Bulk copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/transaction-and-bulk-copy-operations) to dump data in table and then empty datatable and this process goes on.

At the end i commit transaction in the End method and dispose off bulk copy,transaction etc..

When i try to dump records i am getting this error :

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Sales'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Sales'. The duplicate key value is
>   (10364).\r\nThe statement has been terminated

I have columns ordering same as my database table column ordering.I even did truncate statement and also executed this statement :

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(dbo.Discrepancy, RESEED, 0);
```

I got this output :

```
Checking identity information: current identity value '0'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

But still same error even after doing above.

I then tried to insert record from **sql server management studio** and it got inserted but value of Id(pk) is to my surprise is : `10365`

Structure of Sales table :

```
Id(pk)   TestId(F.K)     othercols
```

**Note :** I have set `AutoIncrement on my Id` column.

Code :

```
public class SaveRepo : IDisposable
    {
        DataTable dataTable;
        SqlConnection connection;
        string connectionString;
        SqlTransaction transaction;
        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy;
        int testId,

        public SaveRepo (int testId)//testId=10364
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction);
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Sales";
            this.testId = testId;
            dataTable.Columns.Add("TestId", typeof(int));
        }

       void Dump()
        {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
        }

        public void End()
        {
            transaction.Commit();
            //dispose the stuffs also
        }
    }
```

I did search for this issue and most the soltution was revolving around setting Id to Autoincrement which i already have on my column so i am not getting now whats the problem.

I will appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 4):

I figured out and the problem was `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` which was stopping database from generating identity value for the `AutoIncrement column Id`

I switched to using `SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default` which solves this problem.

So when you have the destination table assign the identity, do not use the `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` option.

Comment: I am still getting the error even with setting the `SQLBulkCopy` option to default.